# Can't see underwater in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

As of patch 1.5, I am completely unable to see underwater in Skyrim.  It's not even that it's murky or dark - it's just a solid grey or green screen.  I can still skim across the surface and see into deep waters, but if I go any deeper than that, nothing is visible.  I can still access items like chests underwater if I figure out their location first (by skimming across the surface) and then point my character there and hope really hard that it gets me to the right place.

I was never able to see much underwater, but I at least used to be able to see small things like wood floating near a shipwreck.  Now, there's just nothing.
I am running the Steam version of Skyrim with graphics on Ultra High, with the high res textures DLC.  I've tried disabling the high res textures (along with all my other mods) and it still happens.

In case it's relevant, my GPU is a GTX 560 Ti.

Does anyone have any solutions to this?

Comment: Does this issue still happen with the latest version of the drivers for your videocard?

Comment: It does.  If you look at my answer, I found a mod that fixes it.  I haven't been able to fix it in the vanilla game.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a mod that fixes this!
AltheaR's Green Water Fix at SkyrimNexus works beautifully, and is compatible with the WATER mod.  I have not tried it without WATER.
[Here is the link.](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/14007/?)

Answer (score 7):

In

```
c:\Users\<your_name>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\SkyrimPrefs.ini
```

you need to write this:

```
[Imagespace]
bDoDepthOfField=0
iRadialBlurLevel=0
```

Comment: I already have the RadialBlur setting, but DepthOfField fixed it, thanks!

Comment: This works, but makes underwater completely bright and sharp, not quite right. Still it is much faster than downloading and installing mods, so have an upvote.

Comment: +1, the DoF setting fixed the problem for me under Parallels. You don't need to edit the INI file directly, though. The setting is right on the first page of the [Skyrim Configurator](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/814/?).